# How to select a value in a multiple values column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `doc` in which there are several fields:

```
user_id | user_name | hostel | summary | branch | year | doc
```

and in this fields entry's are:

```
 user_id user_name   hostel       summary     branch   year     doc
 1       shikhar.447  K.P-6        TnpRegi     CSE      2011     s.JPG
 2 shikhar.447       K.P-6        EndSeme     CSE      2011     placemet.jpeg 
 3 shikhar.447       K.P-9        DDD         I.T      2011     og (1).jpg 
 5 shikhar.447       K.P-6,K.P-9  EEE         CSE,I.T  2011,2012 Drawing6.jpg 
 6 shikhar.447       K.P-6,K.P-9  Xzxx        CSE,I.T  2011,2012 Drawing5.jpg
 8 shikhar.447       K.P-6        Zxzxzx      CSE      2011      Drawing2.jpg
 9 shikhar.447       K.P-6,K.P-9  NLKLD       CSE      2011      Drawing.jpg
```

if It is not showing properly then I would like to clear 
:

```
1 is user_id,shikhar.447 is user_name,K.P-6 is hostel,TnpReg is summary,CSE 
is branch,2011 is year,s.JPG is doc
similarly in some column you can see there are multiple entries with a comma(,)
like K.P-6,K.P-9.
```

So my question is what query i should write so that
if I select hostel="K.P-6",branch="CSE",year=2011
from the checkbox and submit It. It must show me result from doc column values of multiple column values along with single column values.

Initially I have written query like this:

```
SELECT doc,summary FROM doc WHERE hostel="K.P-6" OR branch="CSE" AND year="2011"
```

but it only gives me single value column,It does not search in the multiple values column.

so anyone please help me in this.

Comment: See normalisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bad idea to store multiple values in a single column.

In your case, though, you can use `find_in_set()`:

```
SELECT doc, summary
FROM doc
WHERE find_in_set('K.P-6', hostel) > 0 OR
      find_in_set('CSE', branch) AND
      find_in_set('2011', year);
```

You should also be consistent with the `OR` and `AND` for the conditions.  I'm not sure which you really want, so I haven't change the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Use `like` in where clause:

```
SELECT doc,summary FROM doc WHERE hostel like "%K.P-6%" OR branch like "%CSE%" AND year="2011"
```

However, would recommend to normalize your table